Classifier not available in WEKA (Nominal)
My dataset is german_credit-arf (Updated). I tried several filters, but they didn't work. Please help.
I don't know what the problem is. I select one of the nominal class attributes as the class attribute but doesn't really work.
I tried several times to solve the problem, but I was not able, we always have only one classifier or I don't have one.



You have at least one STRING attribute in your dataset. Convert that into a NOMINAL one and a lot of classifiers will become available. You can use the StringToNominal filter for that.
